# Excel: named range showing 0 even though the linked cell is empty

Tags: excel

I am using the formula:

```
=(Cost!C8)
```

to get values from another sheet using named ranges. I want this to only show a value if there is a value in the corresponding cell of the other sheet, however, this formula returns a value of `0` even if the cell on the other sheet is empty. How can I make it so that the formula returns nothing (is blank) when the cell it refers to is empty?

[image]

Invoice
[image: Cost price sheet]

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of ways to prevent zero's from showing when you refer to a blank cell.

The easiest if probably an `IF` statement.  If your formula is:

```
=(Cost!C8)
```

...use:

```
=IF(Cost!C8="","",Cost!C8)
```

Similarly you could show a default value, or a label like `<No Data>` with a variation:

```
=IF(Cost!C8="","<No Data>",Cost!C8)
```

Note that `Cost!C8` is not a [Named Range](https://support.office.com/article/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64#bmlearn_more_about_using_names); it's a [cell reference](https://techterms.com/definition/cell_reference), referring to another worksheet.

---

### More Information:

- Office Support : [**Create conditional formulas**](https://support.office.com/article/create-conditional-formulas-ca916c57-abd8-4b44-997c-c309b7307831)
- TechRepublic : [**Three ways to hide zero values in an Excel sheet**](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/three-ways-to-hide-zero-values-in-an-excel-sheet/)

Comment: That worked thanks but now in the  "Amount" Column it show "#Value" since that cell is looking at "Qty" x "Unit Price

Comment: @JohnS That would be because you're now trying to multiply by "" which is not a valid value. If you make the cell blank instead of 0 with this method, you need to also add some error checking in downstream formulas to handle that, possibly substituting a 0 if the value is "". See my answer about using formatting to hide the zeroes instead as a possible alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Use,

```
=Cost!C8&""
'alternate for Qty
=TEXT(Cost!C8, "[<>0]0;;;")
'alternate for currency
=TEXT(Cost!C8, "[<>0]$ 0.00;;;")
'alternate for text items
=TEXT(Cost!C8, ";;;@")
```

Granted, this actually converts your true numbers to text-that-looks-like-a-number and that is generally a practice to be avoided but they will be converted back to true numbers through any maths operation like addition or multiplication.

A blank cell is considered numeric by nature. This can be tested with `=ISNUMBER(<blank_cell>)`. The closest thing to a blank number is zero so you are returning those as the value of the blank cells you are linking to.

Comment: THANKS FOR THE INFO! Much appreciation

Answer (score 1):

Use ISBLANK with IF

```
=IF(ISBLANK(Cost!C8),"",Cost!C8)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want it to not be visible, you might consider using conditional formatting to make the text color white when the cell is equal to 0. This way the actual value remains 0 so it won't break downstream formulas.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A nice, slightly simpler, alternative is to concatenate the named range with an empty string.

=MyRange   --> 0

=""&MyRange   --> ""

This is equivalent to TEXT(MyRange) more concise than IF(ISBLANK(MyRange), "", MyRange)